# Blender Knife tool/ boolean

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi guys,

I was wondering if anyone ever experienced this problem where by you cut either by using the knife project tool or Boolean and there's this squeezing/deform on the object you are cutting. It is really annoying as I just want a smooth cut on my mesh. How can I fix this problem?
Please see attached image.

Thank you for the anticipated help.

Comment: The distortions you are seeing are likely caused by non-quad geometry caused by your knife/boolean cuts. It's hard to tell what's going (with the geometry) from the photo because the object is shaded smooth. Turn off smooth shading and any subdivision modifiers and look for faces with more or less than 4 vertices.

Comment: Also, if you have an unapplied boolean in place, tick the box at the top of the modifier that lets you view it in edit mode, and see where the boolean is making cuts in your mesh to facilitate the boolean operation. Sometimes moving it around slightly helps it make better cuts.  Blender has to "choose" how to cut into your mesh to make the bool, but where it chooses can be also be guided by making cuts of your own.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.